# Visual Basic 6 HTML5 Source?

Tags: html, vb6

I want to get the HTML source of a website using Visual Basic 6. And I can, by using this method below:

```
Set objHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    objHttp.Open "GET", "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iUy3_kBme4M", False
    objHttp.SetRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.93 Safari/537.36"
    objHttp.Send ("")
    DoEvents
    strText = objHttp.responseText
    Set objHttp = Nothing
```

However the source I get, is the webpage that is designed from only HTML4 browsers. Shown by the string inside the source: 'Upgrade to a HTML5 Supported Browser'. This is probably because the method I am using is pretty old.

The problem is that I want the source that is designed for HTML5 browsers, as I want to get the URL of the HTML5 player, which is only available in the HTML source of the page when YouTube thinks your browser is HTML5 compliant. The method I am using simulates an HTML4 browser.

Is there a way to grab the HTML source of a webpage as an HTML5 compliant browser in Visual Basic 6?

Comment: You may find some help here, http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version

Comment: If this question is still of any interest... It's not that the method is old, it's simply that YouTube may be sniffing browser capabilities through the use of Javascript, when you're essentially emulating a request made by a Javascript-less/disabled browser. You could try to use the Web Browser Control, or research about some Javascript VMs you could use (like [Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino) + [env.js](http://www.envjs.com/doc/guides#running-rhino) ), provided you can interface them through VB6.